# Using Favourites with Products in shoutem builder

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I've been using / testing the new Shoutem builder, and I've installed both the products and the favourites extensions but am wondering on how I can "link" the two in between. So a user can favourite a specific product and store it in a little dropdown menu. I've searched the documentation and sample apps and I haven't seen the both used in action. Actually I haven't seen the Favourites extension used. Can this be easily accomplished by linking the two extensions?

I am looking for a starting point. So if anyone can guide or link me in the right direction that would be interesting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not documented yet, but we have it implemented. You can check [Books extension](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions). It does just what you're looking for. It requires some changes on Product extension. You can check [here](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-extensions) how you can modify existing extension.

Answer (score 0):

The `app` folder of extension is what is bundled inside of the app. That said, everything that extension exposes in its `app/index.js` is the public API, which can be imported directly inside of the other extension:

```
import {
  Screen
} from 'tom.restaurants'
```

...where `tom` is used as example for developer name and `restaurants` for example for extension name.

All extension share the global app state, which is divided into extension sub-states prefixed by extension full name:

```
{
  'tom.restaurnats': {
      // state of 'tom.restaurants' extension
  }
}
```

This way, you can make the 2 extension communicate.

I would recommend you checking out these 2 guides:

- [Technical overview](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/reference/overview) - explains how the extensions are structured inside the app
- [Modifying extension](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-extensions) - explains how to use parts from other extensions inside of your extension

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply will look into it.